# How to run gunzip command to restore database on alpine linux docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, gunzip

I have a database dump file on test.gz. I used to run gunzip command to import the data from dump file as shown below. But how do I do that on docker container with apline image?

```
gunzip -c test.gz | sed '/\/usr\/lib64\/pgsql\/plpgsql.so/ s/\/usr\/lib64\/pgsql\/plpgsql.so/\/usr\/lib\/pgsql\/plpgsql.so/g' | psql test
```

Comment: Perhaps if you edit your question to provide the exact `docker` command you are using, and the error message, then someone might be able to help.  The problem might be that the image you are using does not include `gunzip`, but that's merely a guess.

Comment: I think that gunzip is provided with gzip. You can install it with: ```apk update``` to build the repo database and ```apk add gzip``` to install it.

Comment: I don't know if sed or psql are in your image, either, though. Both are available the same way, though as ```apk add sed``` and ```apk add postgresql-client```

Comment: Answer: This worked for me: `zcat < test.gz | docker exec -i postgres /bin/bash -c "export PGPASSWORD=password && /usr/bin/psql -U username db_name"`